# How to make plot() from a list which is generated from function?

Tags: r, function, plot

I had created the function which is saving next points to the list.
Now I would like to make a plot from these points. However i would like to change colours of each points from any kind of colour palets.
There is the function:

```
CreatePath <- function (f1, x0, nStep){
f1 <- function( x){
  c( sin( x[1] + x[2]), cos( x[2]) + sin( x[1]))}

x0 <- c( 1, 2)
p1 <- list (x0)
nStep <- 25
k <- 0

while (k < nStep-1) {
  k <- k +1
  p1 <- c (p1, list (f1 (p1 [[length(p1)]])))

}
p1
}
```

Comment: So how exactly are you calling this function? I'm not sure I understand what your question is. What colors are you trying to change? How are you trying to plot this?

Comment: There is only the fun which create a list with points. Now I'am wondering how to use this list to make a plot. the next step is to change color of each point using whole colour palets.

Comment: It is indeed unclear what exactly you are trying to plot and how this function is used to make a plot - can you try to be more specific and provide an example of what you are trying to achieve.